# Creating models with sql data

Tags: sql, django, models

This code

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

produces these sql statements

```
CREATE TABLE myapp_person (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

I want to know if it is possible to do it the other way around. That is  given a .sql file with

```
CREATE TABLE myapp_person (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

should produce models.py file with

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

TIA

Comment: if you create the database with those tables you can then inspectdb - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Comment: my question is can how to create a models.py file with a .sql file. because i have a .sql file(from client) with schema and i have to make a models.py. Instead of writing all the models i want to know if there is any other way to generate models.

Comment: thanks JamesO, i now figured out what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JamesO says in the comments, you can use `inspectdb` for that.

First, create a database, and run that SQL file against that database to create the tables.

Then, run `python manage.py inspectdb` to create the models from the database tables.